# Number of groupings of multi-subsets of combinations using a greedy algorithm

Tags: combinatorics

This question is related to [one I asked previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2223532/number-of-subsets-of-combinations-using-a-greedy-algorithm).

Consider in  sorted order all ${n + k - 1\choose k}$ ways of choosing $k$ integers from $\{0,n-1\}$ with repetitions.  For example, if $n=5$ and $k=3$ we have:

```
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 1),
(0, 0, 2),
(0, 0, 3),
(0, 0, 4),
(0, 1, 1),
[...]
```

Let us now regard each combination as a multi-subset of integers.

Looking at this list from top to bottom, I would like to group consecutive multi-subsets together in a greedy way so that the size of the intersection of all the multi-subsets in a grouping is at least $k-1$.

For $n = 5, k = 3$, the groupings would look as follows:

```
(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 4)
(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4)
(0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4)
(0, 3, 3), (0, 3, 4)
(0, 4, 4)
(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4)]
(1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4)]
(1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4)
(1, 4, 4)
(2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 4)
(2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4)
(2, 4, 4)
(3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 4), (4, 4, 4)
```

I am interested in the number of groupings you get by this greedy algorithm.  We can see that for $n = 5, k = 3$ the number is $14$.

For $n = 4, k = 4$ I believe you get the following $17$ groupings.

```
(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 1, 3)
(0, 0, 2, 2), (0, 0, 2, 3)
(0, 0, 3, 3)
(0, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 2), (0, 1, 1, 3)
(0, 1, 2, 2), (0, 1, 2, 3)
(0, 1, 3, 3)
(0, 2, 2, 2), (0, 2, 2, 3)
(0, 2, 3, 3), (0, 3, 3, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 2, 3)
(1, 1, 3, 3)
(1, 2, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3, 3), (1, 3, 3, 3)
(2, 2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2, 3)
(2, 2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 3, 3)
(3, 3, 3, 3)
```

> Is it possible to give an exact formula for this count for arbitrary positive integers $n> k$?

---

For $n = 2, 3, 4, 5$ I computed the answer for $k = 1,\dots 20$.

- $n = 2$ gives 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11.

This is a simple sequence.

- $n = 3$ gives 1, 3, 5, 8, 11, 15, 19, 24, 29, 35, 41, 48, 55, 63, 71, 80, 89, 99, 109, 120

This is [this OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C%203%2C%205%2C%208%2C%2011%2C%2015%2C%2019%2C%2024%2C%2029%2C%2035%2C%2041%2C%2048%2C%2055%2C%2063%2C%2071%2C%2080%2C%2089%2C%2099%2C%20109%2C%20120&sort=&language=english&go=Search). The interesting fact is that the differences between consecutive numbers is exactly the sequence for $n = 2$.

- $n = 4$ gives $1, 4, 9, 17, 28, 43, 62, 86, 115, 150, 191, 239, 294, 357, 428, 508, 597, 696, 805, 925$. This is [OEIS A005744](https://oeis.org/A005744).

Again the differences between consecutive numbers is exactly the sequence for $n = 3$.

- $n = 5$ gives $1, 5, 14, 31, 59, 102, 164, 250, 365, 515, 706, 945, 1239, 1596, 2024, 2532, 3129, 3825, 4630, 5555$.

This is not in the OEIS but again the differences between consecutive numbers is exactly the sequence for $n = 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the previous question, the differences pattern that you've noted follows from the observation that the greedy algorithm's will never put $(0,n-1,n-1,\dots,n-1)$ and $(1,1,1,\dots,1)$ in the same group for $n>2$. As a result, we can separately figure out what the greedy algorithm does to the multi-subsets that start with $0$, and what it does to the multi-subsets that start with $1, 2, \dots, n$.

Let $m(n,k)$ be the number of multi-subset groupings the greedy algorithm gives us. Then for $n>2$ and $k>1$, we have:

1. The multi-subsets starting with $0$ all agree on that first element. So if we ignore the leading $0$, we are dividing multi-subsets of size $k-1$ into groupings by the greedy algorithm, and we will get $m(n,k-1)$ groupings there.
2. The rest of the multi-subsets do not include $0$ at all. So they only use the $n-1$ values from $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$, and we will get $m(n-1,k)$ groupings there.

So for $n>2$ and $k>1$, we have $m(n,k) = m(n,k-1) + m(n-1,k)$.

When $k=1$, we can put all the one-element multi-subsets into one grouping, so $m(n,1) = 1$.

When $n=2$, our multi-subsets are $\{00\dots00, 00\dots01, 00\dots11,\dots, 01\dots11, 11\dots11\}$. Each shares $k-1$ elements with the multi-subset following it in the lexicographic ordering, but only $k-2$ with the one after that, so all our groupings will be of size $2$, except possibly for the last multi-subset. There are $k+1$ multi-subsets, so $m(2, k) = \left\lceil\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rceil$.

---

So far, we've confirmed that the patterns in your calculations continue. The obstacle to finding a closed form for $m(n,k)$ is that the base case $\left\lceil\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rceil$ is very annoying to deal with.

We can find a formula for fixed $n$ that's nearly-polynomial in $k$ by observing that $\delta(n,k) = \frac{(-1)^k}{2^n}$ also satisfies the recurrence relation $$\delta(n,k) = \delta(n-1,k) + \delta(n,k-1)$$ and therefore $m(n,k) - \delta(n,k)$ does, too. We have $m(2,k) - \delta(2,k) = \frac{k}{2} + \frac34$, which is exactly linear in $k$, and from the formula $$m(n,k) - \delta(n,k) = m(n,1) -\delta(n,1) + \sum_{j=2}^k \bigl(m(n-1,j) - \delta(n-1,j)\bigr)$$ we can get a quadratic formula for $m(3,k) -\delta(3,k)$, a cubic formula for $m(4,k)-\delta(4,k)$, and so on.

We can find all of $m(n,k)$ in the OEIS by looking it up as the triangular table
$$
\begin{matrix}
  1 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 3 & 2 \\
  1 & 4 & 5 & 3 \\
  1 & 5 & 9 & 8 & 3 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{matrix}
$$
where the $j^{\text{th}}$ diagonal from the top is the sequence $m(j+1,k)$. (This is a useful trick when you have a sequence with two parameters.) Read by rows, this triangle is [sequence A181971](http://oeis.org/A181971) in the OEIS, but there is no closed formula there either.

We can also find inequalities bounding $m(n,k)$ that let us at least derive the asymptotics.

- If we define $m_-(n,k) = \frac12\binom{n+k-2}{k-1}$, then $m_-(n,1) = \frac12 \le m(n,1)$ and $m_-(2,k) = \frac k2 \le m(2,k)$. Also, $m_-(n,k) = m_-(n-1,k) + m_-(n,k-1)$, so we can inductively prove that $m_-(n,k) \le m(n,k)$ for all $k$.
- If we define $m_+(n,k)  =\binom{n+k-2}{k-1}$, then $m_+(n,1) = 1 \ge m(n,1)$ and $m_+(2,k) = k \ge m(2,k)$. Also, $m_+(n,k) = m_+(n-1,k) + m_+(n,k-1)$, so we can inductively prove that $m_+(n,k) \ge m(n,k)$ for all $k$.

Therefore we have $$\frac12 \binom{n+k-2}{k-1} \le m(n,k) \le \binom{n+k-2}{k-1}$$ for all $n \ge 2$ and $k \ge 1$, which lets us estimate $m(n,k)$ to within a factor of $2$.

Comment: Thank you. It's a shame it doesn't have such a pretty answer as last time. Are there nice asymptotics as you were able to show previously?

Comment: How about for fixed $k$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Actually, I thought of a much better approach to approximate $m(n,k)$, which I've added to the answer.

Comment: That's awesome!